# Nginx 502 Bad Gateway CentOS7, PHP 7.3.33 FPM

Tags: nginx, centos, php

I am new on CentOS 7. Trying to install Postfix on centOS7 with Nginx. I am following [a tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/redhat/postfixadmin-create-virtual-mailboxes-centos-mail-server), but I get an error message.

I have a 502 Bad Gateway on my server, http://domainname.com , how do I fix it?

```
023/04/29 15:56:32 [crit] 1525#1525: *5994 connect() to unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: IPAddress, server: domainname.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "domainname.com"
```

Comment: Hi All, Issue resolved. By changing fastcgi_pass path in nginx.